# How to disable double click on img tag

Tags: html, angularjs

I have one delete img and on clicking on that it will make an api call and delete the record, but on double click it is making multiple api calls. I tried disabling double click using ng-dblclick="return false;" but no use. can some one help me How to disable double click on img tag using angular js?

PS: I have seen this approach is working on div tag

Thanks

Comment: Disable the click until your record is deleted.

Comment: What about triple clicks? Quintuple clicks? You need to set a flag on that image to ignore all but the first click.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen I see that even ng-disabled is not working.

Comment: @tadman: how can I ignore other clicks, I see that ng-disabled is not working as even I am trying to disable it after the first click.

Comment: I've provided a sample in an answer to show how you might do it. I've taken a few assumptions, since you're not sharing any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could avoid multiple api calls. It may look different than your code, but since you havn't provided any, this is the best I can do.

In your controller you'd have a variable, that you set to true on the first click and set to false when your API call returns with a response. Each time the function making the API call is executed, you check whether this variable is true. If it is, you simply return before making the API call again. This is the code *(I'm skipping best practices here, to keep the sample minimal)*:

```
angular.module('app').controller('myController', function($http){
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.isDeleting = false;

    ctrl.deleteRecord = function(id){
        if(ctrl.isDeleting){
            return;
        }

        ctrl.isDeleting = true;
        $http.delete('[your_api_url]/' + id).finally(function(){
            ctrl.isDeleting = false;
        });
    };
});
```

Then your html would look like this:

```
<img src="images/delete.png" ng-click="$ctrl.deleteRecord(id)" ng-class="{'img-disabled': $ctrl.isDeleting}" />
```

and add some css for visual feedback to the user:

```
.img-disabled {
    cursor: default;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

That's it.

To reiterate, I have no idea how your code looks, so I've taken a few assumptions that you'll have to account for when applying this solution.

Comment: I followed the same logic, but the problem is I am using <img> tag , so I see ng-disabled is not working on <img> tag.

Comment: The `ng-disabled` isn't the essential part of my sample. It's merely for visual feedback to the user. Even without it, with the above code your API wont be called twice. You could do similar with an img tag using `ng-class="{'img-disabled': $ctrl.isDeleting}"`and have some css make the img look disabled. I've removed `ng-disabled` from my example to avoid distracting from the essential of my answer.

Comment: thanks Nikolaj, it is working well with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option would be :

```
<img src="Tulips.png" alt="Add" height="25" width="25" ng-disabled="!isEnabled" ng-click="!isEnabled"></img>

var app = angular.module('main', []).
controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
$scope.isEnabled=true;
});
```